# How much health do sleeping monsters regain?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I know from experience (and [this link](http://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/1at7qw/a_monster_hunter_3u_guide_for_new_players/)) that sleeping monsters regain a portion of their missing health, so long as they aren't interrupted during their nap.

Exactly how much health do sleeping monsters regain? Is it all of their health or only a small portion? I only know that it's enough to keep them from being captured if they were limping beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly it - they regain enough to get out of the limping/capturable threshold. This generally corresponds to around 25% of their maximum HP for the later monsters (anything past a Royal Ludroth) and 40% or so for Ludroths and bird wyverns. Note that attacks on a sleeping monster gain bonus damage, so hitting them while sleeping will push them back below the capturable threshold.